# Would an array be considered a variable?

Tags: c++

My professor does not want any variables in the global constant area which is above main for me. Would this mean that my array which is above main could be considered a variable.

his definition for what can fit in the global constants is

Global Constants - Physics/Math/Conversions/Array Dimension

This is my array

```
string CARDV[13] = {"Ace", "Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack","Queen","King"};
string CARDS[4] = {"Diamonds","Clubs","Heart","Spades"};
```

Comment: If it is an object and it has a name, it is a variable.

Comment: @alterigel Comment revised

Comment: In the letter of the statement, your arrays are variables. In the spirit of the statement, it's not so clear (these appear to be constants in place of magic strings for each card).

Comment: Sounds like your professor is trying to impart some style advise upon his class. I happen to agree with his style, but it's just style. Only he knows what he really wants to appease his matter of style. Therefore, the best answer is "ask your instructor." To answer your question, yes an array is a variable. Constants are also variables. They are just constant. You could probably move those strings elsewhere if you needed to.

Comment: If you really *need* global variables, the next best version would be to declare the variables in `main()` and pass them to your functions (by reference or const reference).

Comment: Would you be allowed to use typed constant variables like `int SEVEN = 7;`?  If so, then you could use the arrays.

Comment: There is also the possibility to put the (const) arrays in a specific namespace to improve encapsulation. Will your professor agree or not is a different story.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider any name for an object that you can apply the address operator on to be a variable.

Although you will not get the contiguous representation in memory, you can accomplish what you are doing with an array with an inline function instead. For example:

```
string CARDV (int idx) {
    switch (idx) {
    case 0: return "Ace";
    //...
    }
}
```